# STM32 Flash mass erase from IAP

Tags: stm32, flash

It might be a silly question but I can't figure out in what cases a flash mass erase from in-application programming (IAP) is relevant, as it would erase the user code as well?

For STM32 devices, ST provides example code in reference manuals like [this one](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031936.pdf):

**A.2.4 Mass erase sequence code example**

```
/* (1) Set the MER bit in the FLASH_CR register to enable mass erasing */
/* (2) Set the STRT bit in the FLASH_CR register to start the erasing */
/* (3) Wait until the BSY bit is reset in the FLASH_SR register */
/* (4) Check the EOP flag in the FLASH_SR register */
/* (5) Clear EOP flag by software by writing EOP at 1 */
/* (6) Reset the PER Bit to disable the mass erase */
FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_MER; /* (1) */
FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_STRT; /* (2) */
while ((FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY) != 0) /* (3) */
{
 /* For robust implementation, add here time-out management */
}
if ((FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_EOP) != 0) /* (4)*/
{
 FLASH->SR = FLASH_SR_EOP; /* (5) */
}
else
{
 /* Manage the error cases */
}
FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_MER; /* (6) */
```

I don't understand how the CPU can reach the instructions from (3) to (6).

Shouldn't they be erased already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program might not be running from flash. The STM32 can run code from SRAM or external memory (via FMC); code running from these locations could safely* erase flash memory.

Some STM32 parts also have two banks of flash memory. Code could be running from one bank and erasing the other bank.

*: Well, *mostly* safely. A power failure during an erase/program cycle would leave the part blank.

Comment: "Do not power down device during update". Of course that statement is worthless some in industrial applications

Comment: if you do your system design correctly then you will have on board power storage (bulk capacitance, battery, ...) that will survive this use case, if it is required as a valid use case.  Industrial or not...if the requirements were not done and/or the system engineering wasnt done then sure you can end up in a situation where the power goes down during update.  and in that case you don tdo a mass erase, you do partial erases and design the software such that it knows which block to choose to run from on the next boot, or second or third boot.